# Play! 2.4 and evolutions fails to deploy on a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

I am trying to deploy a Play! 2.4 project, using eBeans and Evolutions.

However, when trying to deploy on a MySQL database I am getting the following error:

```
[error] p.a.d.e.DefaultEvolutionsApi - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sequence donation_seq' at line 1 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000]
Oops, cannot start the server.
@6ocm6hnl7: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state!
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.checkEvolutionsState(EvolutionsApi.scala:269)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DatabaseEvolutions.evolve(EvolutionsApi.scala:226)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.evolve(EvolutionsApi.scala:81)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:98)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:149)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:52)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

How can I fix this?
Do I have to specify somewhere that I am going to use a MySQL database for production so SQL syntax is created which is compatible with MySQL?

I do have H2 set to MYSQL mode: db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mySql as my development database and upgrading to version 5.6 (5.5 does not accept DateTime(6)) solved the problem.